# How to mix bootstrap into the body of a page

Tags: wordpress

i want to make a page that is NOT the homepage a bit different from the others. I want that in the "middle" of the page there is no simple text or images, but rather a "complex" structure made of an array of divs with hidden sections that can be shown or not, so not the average wordpress content. I kinda made it in a simple local HTML page using bootstrap as framework, now i have to incorporate this into the wordpress page, but i don't know if wordpress CAN do it, using a closed source theme.

What i should do to achieve this?

Comment: sure it can do it (include bootstrap) plop a [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, need to enqueue the bootstrap file into your theme. Then create a page template where you implement design it. Goto your WordPress Theme Directory edit functions.php and enqueue CSS & JavaScript.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function bootstrap_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_assets' );
```

After enqueue assets then need to create a page template into your theme folder. you can set it's your preferred name. I use this time name of file test.php.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Test
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
* @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
*/
get_header();

?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Your Custom Title here</h1>
            <p>Your custom description here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Successfully create page template after need to create a page then select your template & publish it.

If you want to push content via WordPress editor then use the below template.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Test
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
get_header();

?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            the_content();
        // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </main><!-- .site-main -->
    <?php get_sidebar('content-bottom'); ?>
</div><!-- .content-area -->
<?php
get_footer();
```